# Can you time a 'step' taken in gdb?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, gtk

I'm debugging a C library with gdb (gtk).

There is a function which is too slow. I'm trying to figure out which part of the function is causing the delay.

I understand that one option may be to insert manual code / recompile to benchmark segments of code, but is there a way to get the time it took to execute a single step 's' in gdb?

Comment: I think what you need is called a profiler.

Comment: by "too slow" do you mean increments of time that are still mostly imperceptible? If there's a line that takes 1/2 a second or something you could simply cascade a breakpoint from function start to finish until you find it.

Answer (score 6):

For quick-and-dirty profiling, you can put this snippet in your `~/.gdbinit` file:

```
define timeit                                                                                                                                                                             
    python import time
    python start_time = time.time()
    step
    python print("Call took {:.4f} ms".format(time.time() - start_time))
end
document timeit
    Time execution of next function
    Usage: timeit (or ti)
end
```

Here's an example of the `timeit` function in use:

```
$ gdb --quiet --args ./can-daemon --config=../scripts/handlers.lua vcan0
Reading symbols from ./can-daemon...done.
(gdb) b main.cpp:548
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4c5bd4: file /home/evadeflow/projects/info4/can-daemon/src/main.cpp, line 548.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/evadeflow/projects/info4/can-daemon/_build/can-daemon --config=../scripts/handlers.lua vcan0
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Processing messages from: vcan0 

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=3, argv=0x7fffffffdbd8) at /home/evadeflow/projects/info4/can-daemon/src/main.cpp:548
548             auto L = ::InitializeLuaInterpreter(vm, lua_can_handler_map, lua_mqtt_handler_map);
(gdb) ti
(anonymous namespace)::InitializeLuaInterpreter (vm=..., lua_can_handler_map=std::unordered_map with 0 elements, lua_mqtt_handler_map=std::unordered_map with 0 elements)
    at /home/evadeflow/projects/info4/can-daemon/src/main.cpp:469
469 {
Call took 0.0643 ms
(gdb) ti
470     L = luaL_newstate();
Call took 0.0011 ms
(gdb) ti
luaL_newstate () at /home/evadeflow/projects/info4/can-daemon/_build/lua-src/src/lauxlib.c:648                                                                                            
t648      lua_State *L = lua_newstate(l_alloc, NULL);
Call took 0.4028 ms
(gdb) ti
lua_newstate (f=0x7ffff773dbdf <l_alloc>, ud=0x0) at /home/evadeflow/projects/info4/can-daemon/_build/lua-src/src/lstate.c:147
147   void *l = (*f)(ud, NULL, 0, state_size(LG));
Call took: 0.1777 ms
(gdb) ti
l_alloc (ud=0x0, ptr=0x0, osize=0, nsize=616) at /home/evadeflow/projects/info4/can-daemon/_build/lua-src/src/lauxlib.c:630
630   if (nsize == 0) { 
Call took 0.0028 ms
(gdb) ti
635     return realloc(ptr, nsize);
Call took 0.0011 ms
(gdb)
```

Not as accurate as [gprof](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gprof-2.9.1/html_mono/gprof.html), but *much* easier if you just want to get a rough idea of how long each step is taking relative to others.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the right tool for the right job. Use a profiling tool like [sysprof](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Sysprof).

It has seen some [improvements in the version >= 3.20](https://blogs.gnome.org/chergert/2016/08/23/sysprof-builder/).